# How to document overloaded functions in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, function, overloading, doxygen

I am getting a warning message when documenting overloaded functions.

Doxygen version 1.8.7

I have an implementation class and a header class. 
The header class declares two virtual functions, the second of which overloads the first.

ClassA.h

```
    virtual void doSomething(int i); 
    virtual void doSomething(int i,int j);`
```

The implementation class implements each virtual function, as follows

ClassA.cpp

```
    void doSomething(int i) { 
    printf ("doSomething: %d", i); 
    }

    void doSomething(int i,int j) { 
    printf ("doSomething: %d", i); 
    printf ("doSomething: %d", j); 
    }
```

I need to document both doSomething functions in doxygen. 
How do I do it?

I have tried documenting the .h file as follows:

Attempt 1:

ClassA.h

```
    /*! 
    * \fn void doSomething(int i) 
    * do something with i 
    */ 
    virtual void doSomething(int i); `

    /*! 
    * \fn void doSomething(int i, int j) 
    * do something with i and j 
    */ 
    virtual void doSomething(int i,int j);
```

Attempt 2:

```
    /*! 
    * \fn void doSomething(int i) 
    * do something with i 
    */ 
    virtual void doSomething(int i); 

    /*! 
    * \overload void doSomething(int i, int j) 
    * do something with i and j 
    */ 
    virtual void doSomething(int i,int j);
```

I have also tried to document the .cpp file in the same way, with and without documenting the .h file.

However, whichever way I try, I always get the same warning message, which is:

```
    ClassA.cpp: warning: no uniquely matching class member found for void doSomething(int i) 
    Possible candidates: 
    virtual void doSomething(int i) at line 123 of file ClassA.h 
    virtual void doSomething(int i, int j) at line 135 of file Class.h

    ClassA.cpp: warning: no uniquely matching class member found for void doSomething(int i,int j) 
    Possible candidates: 
    virtual void doSomething(int i) at line 123 of file ClassA.h 
    virtual void doSomething(int i, int j) at line 135 of file Class.h
```

Note: Ideally I would prefer to document only the .cpp file and not the .h file in order to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have an [\overload](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdoverload) function in Doxygen which allow you that

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work, see the code for "Attempt 2" above.

Comment: Oh sorry. Check your Doxygen version and if that still does not work try to see if that works with non virtual functions.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.7. Perhaps it will work with non virtual functions, buit unfortunately, they have to remain virtual in this case so I cannot change that.

Comment: It was just to understand whether virtual may be the cause of this behaviour. What happens when you do not precise the line with the \fn command ? (just write the details).

Comment: The result is the same, with the warning message as noted above, Whether, in the .h file, I have:
\fn for both virtual functions, or 
\fn for the first and \overload for the second virtual function, or 
neither \fn nor \overload for either virtual functions

Also, if, instead of adding the doxygen comments (those three permutations mentioned above) to the .h file, I add them to the .cpp file (in fact, this is what I am supposed to do with the code I am working on), I have the same result, with the warning message.

Comment: I have also tried to make those virtual functions in the .h file into non virtual functions, with the same result.